# How to find two strings in consecutive rows and write 0 or 1 accordingly in tabular form in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Given a file **list.txt**:

```
1.inside list.txt
2.Started task: running_temp
3.Finished task: running_temp
4.Started task: walking_temp
5.Finished task: walking_temp
6.Started task: sleeping
```

I want an output file in which will have to check that every start should have a finish. If there is no finish will have to report error.

Comment: How does the expected **output** look?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F: '/^Started/  {a[$2]++} 
         /^Finished/ {a[$2]--} 
         END         {for(k in a) print a[k],k}' file


0  walking_temp
1  sleeping
0  running_temp
```

you'll also get -1 if you have "Finished" without "Started"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need **0** if a `Started` has no `Finished` after itself, otherwise **1**

**file**

```
1.inside list.txt
2.Started task: running_temp
3.Finished task: running_temp
4.Started task: walking_temp
5.Finished task: walking_temp
6.Started task: sleeping
7.Anything ...
```

Note that `6.Started` has no `Finished`

```
perl -nle '$m && print ( /Finished/ ? "$` : 1" : "$` : 0" ); $m = /Started/' file
3. : 1
5. : 1
6. : 0
```

---

The `6.Started` has no `Finished` after itself.